# MySQL decimal round issue

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select values from table. But I've a problem with rounding up digits.
When the number is `152725.6050` I want the result `152725.60`. but it displays `122725.61.` 
It's running very well, only the problem with decimal point like `0.6051,0.1251` etc.

```
select 
d.date1,
ylit,
round(d.fat,1),
round(d.snf,1),
rs,
round(rs*ylit,2),
nlit,
kalit,
jlit 
from daily_milk as d, 
$rate_chart[0] as r 
where d.fat=r.fat 
&& d.snf=r.snf 
&& mtype='$mtype' 
&& scode='$society_code_op[0]' 
&& shift='सकाळ' 
&& d.date1 between '$date1' and '$date2' 
&& d.date1 between r.date1 and r.date2 
order by d.date1
```

Comment: Simply fetch the value from the database as it is and do the formatting PHP-side, **just before it's output to the user** (you can use `number_format()`, `round()` etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this in SQL you can do

```
FLOOR(column_name * 100) / 100
```

instead of

```
ROUND(column_name, 2)
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/34068)** demo

Answer (score 0):

For PHP :

```
$var = 1.787;
echo number_format((float)(FLOOR($var * 100) / 100), 2, '.', '');
```